# Insignificant result with one-way anova but significant with two-way anova?

Tags: anova

I'm working on `lung` dataset of `ISwR` package in R.

A book by Peter Dalgaard,  has assigned me to answer this question:
7.2 In the lung data, do the three measurement methods give systematically
different results? If so, which ones appear to be different?

In this data, volume is a numeric vector and there are two factor variables: method(A, B, C) and subject(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6).

So What I did was simply,

```
anova(lm(volume~method, data=lung))
```

Its result was just an insignificant one.

I found out in the answer section of the book that I also have to put in 'subject', as in

```
anova(lm(volume~method+subject, data=lung))
```

And it gave me the right answer, showing significance for both method and subject.

But I cannot understand the result; Why is it insignificant with the one-way anova? And why did it become significant with one more variable added?

To faithfully answer the question, don't I have to input only `method`?

Comment: Did each subject get assessed with all three methods? If so, you need to account for this in your analysis.

Answer (score 0):

In your model with `method` as only predictor variable, you do not take into account that the three data points from each subject are not independent from each other. That is, you treat your predictor variable as a between-subjects variable while it is in fact a within-subjects variable. This reduces the power of your analysis because you do not factor out the variance explained by overall differences between subjects.

I'm not completely sure about the maths behind this, but adding `subject` as a predictor variable makes your analysis treat `method` as a within-subjects variable. You can see this when you run the ANOVA with a package that let's you directly specify within-subjects variables, e.g. the `ez` package:

```
ezANOVA(lung, volume, wid=subject, within=.(method))
```

That should give you the numerically identical result for `method` as in the textbook solution.